# Shortcut key visible on button in Windows CE 6.0 .NET application

Tags: .net, vb.net, compact-framework, windows-ce

I'm developing a sample application for a Windows CE 6.0 project and 1 of the requirements is having keys mapped to a button with the shortcut key visible as text in the upper corner of the button.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOWeJ.png)

This isn't something I've seen in the standard .NET controls.

Is there a way of doing this using the .NET controls or is it something I need a custom control for?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to create a custum control or subclass the standard window forms button. See subclass example with picture button [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446518.aspx).